# How to use "Segment" in "GoogleAnalytics" service connection?

Tags: external-calls, webservices

I‘m trying to make a GA request using the "Segment" parameter but as the the Wolfram Documentation states, Segment ID must be an integer:

*segments the data returned for your request; accepts an integer Segment ID*

However, GA uses alphanumerics for Segment ID since Release 2013-07-15 (July 16, 2013) https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/changelog

Is there a way to transform alphanumeric GA Segment IDs to integers or is the service connection outdated?

Comment: The service connection is outdated. Run ``PacletFind["ServiceConnection_GoogleAnalytics"][[1]]["Location"]//SystemOpen`` and then find where in the `"GoogleAnalytics.m"` (well that's probably its name) file they make that check. Disable it. Then all will be well.